# My discord bot doesn't play mp3 file and it gives no errors

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I tried debugging but it reaches everything fine and then nothing happens

To clarify `filename` is the path to the file including the file

```
async def playing_video(ctx, filename):
    global vc
    voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    channel = None

    # Check if user is in a voice channel
    if voice_channel != None:
        channel=voice_channel.name
        print(f"Voice Channel: {voice_channel}")
        vc = await voice_channel.connect()

       # It reaches here with the right path to the file and what looks like the right vc but then nothing happens.

        vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(filename), after=lambda e: print('done', e))
    else:
        await ctx.send("You must use *join first!")
```

All I found is a guy who had the same problem as me but he just wrote "I solved it" without saying how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like such an idiot. The problem was that the bot didn't have permission to speak.

I am leaving this up because I am sure someone will do the same.